# xUnit.net Test Stripper [to remove test code embedded in binaries prior to deployment/shipping]

Tags: c#, unit-testing, msbuild, nunit, xunit.net

Is there a Test Stripper (as defined in [xUnit Test Patterns](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00132S6V4)) available that supports removing classes containing methods tagged as [Fact]s etc. plus the dependency on xunit.dll from binaries [as part of a build process] ?

Further details of the full requirements and context are at [this xUnit CodePlex post](http://xunit.codeplex.com/Thread/View.aspx?ThreadId=69022).

Failing that (something that removes the tests and the reference to the DLL), does anyone have a utility/proven clean approach to removing the xunit.dll dependecy without too much monkeying around in .vcproj files etc.

Open source preferred. A cleanly written one for NUnit might potentially serve as a base.

*NB: I'm aware of the negatives of embedding code into assemblies - this question isnt about that (unless you feel after reading the codeplex thread that some key points are being missed).*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted in the [codeplex post where I specified the requirements](http://xunit.codeplex.com/Thread/View.aspx?ThreadId=69022), I implemented a basic stripper with Mono.Cecil but ended up leveraging the fact that [unused references get optimised out in a release build](http://bytes.com/topic/net/answers/444853-conditional-assembly-reference) to 'strip' tests out by [excluding them based on a #define, which I control from outside via the MSBuild invocation](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/msbuild/thread/ed141cf9-4f6a-4ed4-b3e8-e23794fe017f)

Answer (score 2):

If your unit tests are placed in a project resp. assembly of their own there should be no need to strip test classes prior to deployment. What's wrong about this approach?

Comment: Read http://xunit.codeplex.com/Thread/View.aspx?ThreadId=69022 (In short, you need to make more stuff public and/or conditionally compile in lots of stuff to make stuff visible to the tests)

Comment: And you end up with twice as many projects. It's one of the [misguided, but no less real for that] motivations for MSTest's publicize.exe utility for creating 'Private Accessor' assemblies

Comment: @Miriam: As discussed in the CodePlex post, the key problem with InternalsVisibleTo is how that gets messy with Strong Naming. (And the fact you end up with twice as many projects)