# How to invoke static method in C#4.0 with dynamic type?

Tags: c#, .net, dynamic, c#-4.0

In C#4.0, we have dynamic type, but how to invoke static method of dynamic type object?

Below code will generate exception at run time. The **dynamic** object is from C# class, but it could be object from other languages through DLR. The point is not how to invoke static method, but how to invoke static method of **dynamic** object which could not be created in C# code.

```
class Foo
{
    public static int Sum(int x, int y)
    {
        return x + y;
    }
}

class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        dynamic d = new Foo();
        Console.WriteLine(d.Sum(1, 3));

    }
}
```

IMHO, **dynamic** is invented to bridge C# and other programming language. There is some other language (e.g. Java) allows to invoke static method through object instead of type.

BTW, The introduction of C#4.0 is not so impressive compared to C#3.0.

Answer (score 13):

This is not supported directly by C# 4 but there's an interesting workaround in this blog post: http://blogs.msdn.com/davidebb/archive/2009/10/23/using-c-dynamic-to-call-static-members.aspx

Answer (score 10):

While C# doesn't support it, the DLR does. You can programmatically access the dlr calls with [Dynamitey](https://github.com/ekonbenefits/dynamitey/wiki/UsageReallyLateBinding#static-methodsproperties)

```
var staticContext = InvokeContext.CreateStatic ;

Console.WriteLine(Dynamic.InvokeMember(staticContext(typeof(Foo)), "Sum", 1,3));
```

Answer (score 7):

One possible workaround would be to use reflection.

```
dynamic d = new Foo();

var sum = (int)d.GetType()
                .GetMethod("Sum")
                .Invoke(d, new object[] { 1, 3 });
Console.WriteLine(sum);
```