# How to GetType of Defined text

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010

Can I do this in C#:

```
string str="string";
Type typ=typeof(str);
```

Can any one help me to create generic type converter without do multiple conditions

Comment: `str.GetType()` or `typeof(string)`

Comment: Regarding type conversions, have a look at [my answer on another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18360322/is-using-successive-tryparse-calls-a-sound-way-to-guess-a-strings-real-type/18362420#18362420)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The closest you will be able to get is by using [`Type.GetType(System.String)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3f99sx1.aspx).

This requires using the assembly qualified name, unless the type is defined in mscorlib, where you will be able to use just the namespace qualified name.

e.g for a class from mscorlib:

```
Type stringType = Type.GetType("System.String");
```

or for a class not from mscorlib:

```
Type dependencyPropertyType = Type.GetType("System.Windows.DependencyProperty, WindowsBase, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35");
```