# C# Dynamically parse user input to string, int, double, decimal, datetime, bool, etc

Tags: c#

How can I dynamically parse a value entered by user to a certain type?

If I have a text box, where users might enter whatever they want, how can I parse that value dynamically and return the appropriate type?

```
 public dynamic ParseValue(dynamic value)
 {
     return //TO DO
 }
```

If user enters the following values:

- 06.18.2015 10:23:00 // return DateTime
- some text // return string
- 10.23 //return double/decimal
- true/True/false/False // return bool not string
- 10 //return int

Is it the right way to use the type.TryParse, and check for each type if it's valid? Of course I'll have to check first if it's bool and then string, otherwise if the value is `true/True/false/False` will result in string rather than bool.

Comment: Is the input parameter always a string? The input param type should be string then..

Comment: Yes, always a string, a textbox

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2961656/generic-tryparse

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You do not need to use `dynamic` keyword. Because your source values always are `string`.

It is good to write generic method to parse values from `string`. 
You can use `TypeConverter` method of `TypeDescriptor` class to write this kind of method.

from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2961656/generic-tryparse) answer

```
public static T Convert<T>(this string input)
{
    var converter = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(T));
    if(converter != null)
    {
        //Cast ConvertFromString(string text) : object to (T)
        return (T)converter.ConvertFromString(input);
    }
    return default(T);
}
```

Comment: You should rather flag the question duplicate than copy/paste...

Comment: @NamBình Sorry I thought that question is different because of mentioning `dynamic` keyword.

Answer (score 0):

Although I can not understand why you need this the following may work:

```
   // since user will enter text value should be string
    public dynamic ParseValue(string value)
    {
        DateTime tempDateTime;
        if (DateTime.TryParse(value, out tempDateTime))
        {
            return tempDateTime;
        }

        int tempInt;
        if(int.TryParse(value, out tempInt))
        {
            return tempInt;
        }

        // also process other types like double etc. before falling back to string
        return value;
    }
}
```

But I suspect this will be a solution since you will need to get the exact type to process return value in the caller function.

Answer (score 0):

Yes imho you will need to use type.TryParse and build your own logic for type priorities

[Generic TryParse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2961656/generic-tryparse)

```
public dynamic ParseValue(string value)
 {
     return //TO DO
 }
```