# Cast from with generics from long to int using object instance

Tags: c#, generics, casting

I am casting dynamically with generics and have come across a problem when casting from `long` to `int`. The problem basically boils down to the following:

While this works:

```
 long l = 10;
 int i = (int) l;
```

This does not:

```
 long l = 10;
 object o = l;
 int i = (int)o;
```

So the problem is that I have an object as variable of type `object` but the instance behind is of type `long` and I want to cast this to an `int`. What I have found so far is this article: [Representation and identity (Eric Lippert)](http://ericlippert.com/2009/03/03/representation-and-identity/).

So what would be valid is this:

```
 long l = 10;
 object o = l;
 int i = (int)(long)o;
```

What I have tried is this:

```
 long l = 10;
 object o = l;
 int i = (int) Convert.ChangeType(o, typeof(long));
```

But this does not work. Now the question is how can I cast dynamically without `System.InvalidCastException`?

Currently I have is this (and it does NOT work):

```
public T Parse<T>(object value){
    return (T) Convert.ChangeType(value, value.GetType());
}
```

How can I make it work and be able to pass an object of type `long` with T beeing `int`.

Comment: I don't get it. You found a way that works (casting the object to its original type), but it seems like you want to do it in a more convoluted manner? Also, are you not worried about the possible loss of data in going from a 64-bit integer to a 32-bit?

Comment: Can't you just say `return (T)value;`

Comment: @ChristophKn No, it will throw an InvalidCastException.

Comment: @user1666620 No I am not concerned about the data-loss. (In fact I am working with int values but for some reason receive them as long type values when communicating over signalR websockets. But that is not the scope of the question.)

Comment: Surely you want to use `Convert.ChangeType(value, typeof(T))`? Using `value.GetType()` is a no-op.

Comment: @Lee This is the solution. Thanks!

Comment: Why store a `long` and cast it back as an `int`?

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen I receive the value as long type from an in between library. What I showed here is a minimal example. (see my other comments)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of this:

```
long l = 10;
object o = l;
int i = (int) Convert.ChangeType(o, typeof(long));
```

Just ask `Convert` to give you an `int`, as that's what you want:

```
long l = 10;
object o = l;
int i = (int) Convert.ChangeType(o, typeof(int));
```

The `Convert` class with use the `IConvertable` interface to do the conversion for you.

Using this approach you can write your `Parse` function like this:

```
T Parse<T>(object value)
{
  return (T) Convert.ChangeType(value, typeof(T));
}
```

And call it like this:

```
long l = 10;
object o = l;
int i=Parse<int>(o);
```

Answer (score 0):

`long` to `int` is type casting, when you doing this you are just changing value of one type to another similar type, in some case that may lead to value loss, and compiler knows how to perform so.

`object` to `int` is type conversion. you are attempting to change the underlying type. Hence the **`runtime`** error.

Have a look at [Casting and Type Conversion](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173105.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) & [Boxing & Unboxing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yz2be5wk.aspx)

Comment: I don't know what the type is so I reference it as an `object` even though the actual instance is of type `long`. The question is about generic casting.

Answer (score 0):

How about this

```
return (T) TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(T)).ConvertFromString(value.ToString());
```

It will still fail if your long value is too big for an int so you would still need to deal with that.

Look at this
[Generic TryParse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2961656/generic-tryparse)