# shorthand c# if statement for text field being empty

Tags: c#, if-statement

Is there a way to shorthand the if/else statement below?

```
if (txtInvoiceDate.Text != "")
{
    query.Parameters.AddWithValue("@InvoiceDate", SqlDbType.SmallDateTime).Value = DateTime.Parse(txtInvoiceDate.Text.ToString());
}
else
{
    query.Parameters.AddWithValue("@InvoiceDate", SqlDbType.SmallDateTime).Value = DBNull.Value;
}
```

Comment: You can use a ternary statement

Comment: Shorthand isn't always better, what is it you're trying to achieve?

Comment: is there typo beetwen `query.Parameters` and `Parameters`? or are they really different?

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary No, it's the same. I missed the query on the first one. Edited the question to be correct

Comment: answers engaged as soon as you edited your question. lol :D

Answer (score 3):

```
        query.Parameters.AddWithValue("@InvoiceDate", SqlDbType.SmallDateTime).Value =
            string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtInvoiceDate.Text)
                ? (DateTime?)DBNull.Value
                : DateTime.Parse(txtInvoiceDate.Text);
```

Answer (score 2):

- You call `String.ToString()` unnecessarily.
- Your code doesn't handle the case of non-empty, but invalid, input.

My version:

```
{
    Object paramValue = DBNull.Value;
    DateTime value;
    if( DateTime.TryParse( txtInvoiceDate.Text, out value ) ) {
        paramValue = value;
    }
    query.Parameters.AddWithValue("@InvoiceDate", SqlDbType.SmallDateTime).Value = paramValue;
}
```

Note my use of `{}` anonymous scopes so the `paramValue` and `value` variables don't pollute the local scope.

If you find yourself doing this often, you can change it to a method:

```
static SqlParameter AddDateParameter(SqlCommand cmd, String parameterName, String inputValue) {
    SqlParameter p = cmd.CreateParameter();
    p.Name = parameterName;
    p.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.SmallDateTime;
    cmd.Parameters.Add( p );

    DateTime value;
    if( DateTime.TryParse( inputValue, out value ) ) {
        p.Value = value;
    }
    else {
        p.Value = DBNull.Value;
    }
    return p; // return `p` in case the caller wants to modify the parameter further
}
```

Used like so:

```
AddDataParameter( query, "@InvoiceDate", txtInvoiceDate.Text );
```

As an aside, it might be an idea to replace `txtInvoiceDate` (which I assume is a `TextBox`) with a `DateTimePicker` control instead, which would outright prevent invalid input and also expose a strongly-typed `DateTime` value directly, without the need to use `DateTime.TryParse`.

Answer (score 1):

```
query.Parameters.AddWithValue("@InvoiceDate", SqlDbType.SmallDateTime).Value = 
    (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtInvoceDate.Text) ? 
      DateTime.Parse(txtInvoiceDate.Text) : 
      DBNull.Value);
```

Comment: Please remove the completely unnecessary .ToString() on .Text

Answer (score 0):

I would create a simple extension for this.

```
public delegate bool TryParseHandler<T>(string value, out T result);

public static T? DbNullOrValue<T>(this string input, TryParseHandler<T> handler) where T : struct, IConvertible
{
    T res;
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(input))
        if(handler(input, out res))
            return res;

    return null;
}
```

which can then be called anywhere like:

`"12/13/15".DbNullOrValue<DateTime>(DateTime.TryParse)`

EDIT: Taking from [Generic TryParse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2961656/generic-tryparse) I update the above code to also check if it can be converted before actually converting, pretty interesting technique.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the answers guys. When I tried to use:

```
query.Parameters.AddWithValue("@InvoiceDate", SqlDbType.SmallDateTime).Value =
        string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtInvoiceDate.Text)
            ? DBNull.Value
            : DateTime.Parse(txtInvoiceDate.Text);
```

I was getting an error that said

> Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is
>   no implicit conversion between 'System.DBNull' and 'System.DateTime'

In order to solve this, I had to use:

```
query.Parameters.AddWithValue("@InvoiceDate", SqlDbType.SmallDateTime).Value = (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtInvoiceDate.Text) ? (DateTime?)null : DateTime.Parse(txtInvoiceDate.Text));
```

Comment: I wouldn't suggest doing another cast to datetime? just to convert it to a null. Are you doing this more than once? You probably will want to break this off.

Comment: @Dispersia There is a bunch of text fields that will be using this, and I can't seem to get it to work without the DateTime cast

Comment: Did you try my answer to see if it fit your needs?

Comment: @Dispersia If you mean by using null instead of (DateTime?)null, then yes I did. It didn't work. I was getting the same error

Comment: No, my actual answer, I suggested an extension method to simplify this greatly.

Comment: @Dispersia I will try it out on Tuesday when I get to work.