# RuntimeBinderException with dynamic object calling public static method TryParse

Tags: c#

I am trying to call the public TryParse method via a dynamic object but I am getting a RuntimeBinderException... "System.Reflection.TypeInfo does not contain a definition for TryParse". The dynamic object at runtime has type System.Boolean and this class has that public method defined.

Note. Reason for this is to create a generic TryParse method with additional error checking that will be used repeatedly through the application.

Here's the code to reproduce the problem:

```
    private (bool Success, T Value) TryParse<T>(string strval)
    {
        (bool Success, T Value) retval;
        dynamic dtype = typeof(T);
        retval.Success = dtype.TryParse(strval, out retval.Value);
        return retval;
    }
```

In my case, I am testing the method with TryParse("true").
What am I doing wrong?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Bool.TryParse` is a static method.  `Bool` and `typeof(Bool)` are not the same thing.  `typeof(Bool)` returns a `System.Reflection.TypeInfo` (which inherits from `System.Type`) object which has meta data about the boolean type, and does not have a method call `TryParse`.

You **could** use reflection to get the `TryParse` method from the type object

```
Type tType = typeof(T);
object[] args = { "true", false };
MethodInfo tryParseMethodInfo = tType.GetMethod("TryParse", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public);
bool result = (bool)tryParseMethodInfo.Invoke(null, args);
```

But you might be better off using `System.Convert`.  You could also look at using the approach described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2961656/generic-tryparse)

Comment: I was trying to avoid reflection. Thought (apparently incorrectly) dynamic might be a possible way. Leaning toward using Charlie Brown's answer on the link you provided in order to have a generic function that accomplishes TryParse + application specific error checking.