# Dynamic variable in throw statement fails with CS0155

Tags: c#

I encountered a bizarre bug (?) while refactoring some code.

For some unknown reason, I get a compiler error when passing a dynamic variable to a static method in a throw statement.

```
dynamic result = comObj.getfoo(bar);

// ....

throw ApiException.FromResult(result);
```

> **Error CS0155**
>   The type caught or thrown must be derived from System.Exception

This makes no sense as the returned value *is* derived from [System.Exception](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.exception(v=vs.110).aspx).

Furthermore, what makes me lean toward this being a bug, is that error can be circumvented by either:

1. changing `dynamic` to `var`

```
  var result = 0;
```

2. by casting the variable to `object`.

```
  throw ApiException.FromResult((object)result);
```

Any ideas?

---

[Live on dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Tdf1TR)

```
/* PS: code omitted for brevity */

using System;

public class Program
{

    public class ApiException : Exception
    {

        public static ApiException FromResult(object result)
        {
            return new ApiException();
        }

    }

    [STAThread]
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {       
        dynamic result = 0;
        throw ApiException.FromResult(result);  
    }

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to invoke static method in C#4.0 with dynamic type?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2825355/how-to-invoke-static-method-in-c4-0-with-dynamic-type)

Comment: This happens for both Roslyn and the old compiler.

Comment: @IanMundy: No; that's a regular static method.

Comment: @SLaks Correct, I tested with both compilers. So, bug or by design?

Comment: If `result` is `dynamic` then the expression `ApiException.FromResult(result)` is also `dynamic` which is not derived from `Exception`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is "expected" behavior as any statement containing `dynamic` is treated as if its result type is `dynamic`, which can't be cast to `Exception` at compile time.

```
dynamic x = new Exception();
throw x; // fails to compile as x's type 
         // is not known to derive from `Exception` at compile time

throw (Exception)x; // works
```

Your workarounds change compile-time result from `dynamic` to proper type and hence compile correctly.

```
dynamic result =....
throw 
      // compile type here is "dynamic" as one parameter is `dynamic`
      ApiException.FromResult(result);
```

This works because `var` is not `dynamic` ([What's the difference between dynamic(C# 4) and var?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/961581/whats-the-difference-between-dynamicc-4-and-var))

```
var result = ... // any non dynamic type - staticly know at compile time
throw 
      // compile type here is ApiException because type of parameter is known
      // at compile time 
      ApiException.FromResult(result);
```

Similar problem happen when you try to invoke extensions on `dynamic` result - [Extension method and dynamic object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5311465/extension-method-and-dynamic-object)

---

To address concern why "throw" is different from function call (that happily handle resolution at run-time): specification for `throw` *statement* requires type of expression to be Exception unlike for *expressions* including method invocation where there are rules for dynamic binding (7.2. Static and Dynamic Binding).

Interesting note that other statement like `while` are happy with `dynamic` value at compile time and I don't see reason why they behave differently.

Excerts from C# 5 spec

> 7.2 Static and Dynamic Binding
>   ...
>   When an operation is dynamically bound, little or no checking is performed by the compiler. Instead if the run-time binding fails, errors are reported as exceptions at run-time.
>   The following operations in C# are subject to binding:
>   •  Method invocation: e.M(e1,…,en)
>   ...
>   8.9.5 The throw statement:
>   ...
>   The expression must denote a value of the class type System.Exception, of a class type that derives from System.Exception or of a type parameter type that has System.Exception (or a subclass thereof) as its effective base class.

Comment: That's it. So, should I blame the IDE then? When I hover `FromResult` it still reads `ApiException`.

Comment: @Bjørn-RogerKringsjå sure... Also at that point IDE has hard choice of trying to be useful in general and showing type for method or being 100% compatible with compiler which probably require more info than intellisense has at that point. I believe intellisense for `dynamic` is best effort as everything can change at run time so I would not expect much from it.

Comment: "[an object of type dynamic bypasses static type checking](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/dd264736.aspx)"; does this mean that dynamic bypasses compile-time static type checking *except* for `Exception` types? Or are these statements different than "static type checking": "// fails to compile as x's type 
         // is not known to derive from `Exception` at compile time"?

Comment: @Quantic I added my understanding of the reason to the post - `throw` is statement with particular requirement which don't have special case for `dynamic`.

Answer (score 2):

Most of the operations involving `dynamic` result in `dynamic` as result type, hence you see the error. *(and as explained in the other [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40027028/961113))*.

But it is not that all operations involving `dynamic` results in dynamic type, for example with constructor. If you have a constructor in your class:

```
public ApiException(object result)
{

}
```

and you try to invoke it like:

```
dynamic result = 0;
throw new ApiException(result);
```

There will be no error.

See: [Using Type dynamic (C# Programming Guide)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/dd264736.aspx)

> The result of most dynamic operations is itself dynamic.

and also:

> Operations in which the result is not dynamic include conversions from
>   dynamic to another type, and constructor calls that include arguments
>   of type dynamic.

The reason it works with `var` is because it is a strongly typed variable at the time of compilation.