# Asserting Exceptions for Private Methods

Tags: c#, exception, nunit, assert, private-methods

I am unit-testing private methods in C# using NUnit.

For example, my method (if public) is expected to throw an `ArgumentNullException`. I can assert that the method throws an `ArgumentNullException` like so: `Assert.Throws<ArgumentNullException>(() => method.Call());`

However, since I am invoking a private method using reflection, I would assert a `TargetInvocationException` for the method that throws an `ArgumentNullException` like so: `Assert.Throws<TargetInvocationException>(() => methodInfo.Invoke(obj, new object[] { params }));`

I would like to assert an `ArgumentNullException` instead of a `TargetInvocationException` for that private method so I can scan over its code and know what its expected to do rather than to debug to find out.

How would I assert for the actual exception, instead of a `TargetInvocationException`?

**NOTE**:
This question is not addressing the theory behind unit-testing public vs. private methods. My team and I have made the decision to unit-test the private methods, and whether or not that is the way to unit-test is irrelevant to this question. See the most upvoted answer on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1506584/1121302) question to understand our rationale.

Comment: Whether or not this is a good idea is one thing, but could you check the `InnerException` property?

Comment: Thanks @GeorgeDuckett for the guiding me in the right direction.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Found my answer:

```
var exception = Assert.Throws<TargetInvocationException>(() => methodInfo.Invoke(obj, new object[] { params }));
Assert.IsInstanceOf<Exception>(exception.InnerException);
```

**UPDATE**

`Assert.IsNotNull(exception.InnerException)` lets me know that an inner exception exists. `Assert.IsInstanceOf<Exception>(exception.InnerException);` will assert any type of `Exception` thrown. I agree that both ways tell us that there is an inner exception.

**However.....what if I want to assert for a specific type of inner exception?**

For example, if my method throws an `ArgumentNullException`, then I cannot assert for that by doing `Assert.IsInstanceOf<FileNotFoundException>(exception.InnerException);` Using `Assert.IsNotNull` lets me know that an inner exception exists, but it does not reveal the type of the inner exception. Therefore, this is why I prefer using `IsInstanceOf` in this case.

Comment: FYI -- this is the same as checking that the InnerException is not null since all that will be true of any exception.

Answer (score 3):

Make an extension method on Assert, i.e "ThrowsInnerException" that take a func, wrap with a Try/Catch and throw the InnerException (which, in your case, correspond to the ArgumentNullException)

Here is a piece of code (**untested** & **doesn't compile**, as I typed it without editor, but it should give you the idea)

```
public static class AssertExtension 
    {
        public static void ThrowsInnerException<T>(Action action) 
        {
            Assert.Throws<T>(delegate() {
                try { action(); }
                catch (Exception exc) { throw exc.InnerException; }
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer the question asked.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that unit-testing private methods is good idea? Because sounds like it isn't.

It's better to test public method that is calling private method.

**Update**

What's more, despite I didn't see your code, but I think it's better to put parameters validation to public methods and test them.

**Update2**
Found pretty similar [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/250692/how-do-you-unit-test-private-methods)

**Update3**
**Approach that I was using in similar case**(for mocking `private` fields) was just to mark `private` methods as `internal` and to add `InternalsVisibleTo(<assembly_with_unit_tests>)` attribute to assembly under test.
It's not good idea(actually I was against this when it was proposed in team on one of design session, because it's not right, not pure, etc), but as the result it saved a lot of time for writing unit-tests.

Comment: The public method that calls these private methods have been tested. As I stated above, my team has determined to test the private methods as there are many parts within the public method.

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1506427/unit-testing-private-code). The most upvoted answer explains our rationale in taking this route.

Comment: Testing the public method necesarily means you have tested the private methods. They are not distinct.