# How do I access private members from a VB.NET test case?

Tags: vb.net, unit-testing

I'm using VS 2010 Professional built-in test cases. I've got a class that has a read-only property that looks something like this:

```
    Private _server As IServer = Nothing
    Public ReadOnly Property Server()
        Get
            If _server Is Nothing Then
                RemotingSetup.RegisterHttpBinaryChannel()
                _server = RemotingFactory.CreateProxy(Of IServer)(Options.DevLocal)
            End If

            Return _server
        End Get
    End Property
```

In my test cases I want to make a fake server implementation so I can test some of the class methods without actually hitting the server. I've looked around and have seen the `InternalsVisibleTo` attribute, but that seems to only allow access to `Friend`-level members.

Is there any simple way to get access to these members, aside from declaring them Public/Friend?

Comment: check this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/250692/how-do-you-unit-test-private-methods

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apart from using a mocking library that will mock private members (such as [TypeMock](http://www.typemock.com/), which is the only one I know of that does this), you are out of luck, at least when it comes to testing this particular class directly.

There are other possibilities - you can subclass from this class and only override this property. This will let you test all other functionality. Of course, this assumes that the class isn't sealed (NotInheritable).