# Unit testing private members using *_Accessor

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, testing, tfs

I am currently working on a C# solution in VS 2010.

In order to write sufficient unit tests for my business processes I am using the Accessor approach to access and change the internals of my business objects.

The issues that has arisen on my TFS build server now that I have added Accessors to my objet assembly in a number of other test assemblies, when my test run not all the test pass, some fail with a warning along the lines of:

```
... <Test failed message> ....
... Could not load file 'ObjectLibrary_Accessor, Version=0.0.0.0, 
        Culture=neutralm PublicKeyToken=ab391acd9394' or one of its dependencies.
...
...
```

I believe the issue is that as each test assembly is compiled a ObjectLibrary_Accessor.dll is created with a different strong name. Therefore when some of the tests are compiled the strong name check fails with the above error even-though the dll is in the expected location.

I see a number of options, none of which are particularly attractive, these include:

1. Not using the _Accessor approach.
2. Set a different XX_Accessor.dll for each test assembly - Is it possible to change the name of the generated assembly to avoid the clash?
3. Change my integration build to use a different binaries folder for each test project(how?)
4. Other options I do not know about?

I would be interested in any advice or experience people have had of this issue, solutions and workarounds (although I do not have time to change my code so option 1 is not a favorate).

Answer (score 3):

The `Accessor` approach is a bit fragile, as you've seen.

You can make internal items visible to your test code by using the `InternalsVisibleTo` assembly attribute.

If you want to get at private methods and you're using .NET 4.0 then consider using something like [Trespasser](http://nuget.org/packages/Trespasser) to make this easier.

For more options see the answers for this question: [How do you unit test private methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/250692/63179)