# How do I unit test functions on iOS that should not be publicly exposed?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, unit-testing, swift

I have a plist file that contains a top level dictionary and that dictionary contains an array of strings.

I want to test:

1. That the dictionary is not nil
2. That the array is not nil
3. And that the array has at least one valid string object in it

I have these unit tests running great. Very de-coupled. But the problem is I have to make the class functions public in order for Xcode XCTest to be able to test them. These 3 functions are simply helper functions to get the actual data we need.

How do I employ proper visibility on these helper functions while keeping my tests? No one needs to know about these  3 functions, but I want them tested.

Comment: Are you sure you should? See the second answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/250692/how-do-you-unit-test-private-methods

Comment: I see what you are saying - test only the public API. But what about when I want to test if a Plist exists? Maybe someone accidentally deleted it from the project. If so I would immediately know what the problem is. This isn't a public api function but still needs to be tested (I think). What do you think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two solid options for this:

1. Create a second `.h` file named something like `MyClass_TestHelpers.h` where you can declare those methods you need.
2. Create a category on the class titled something like 'TestHelpers'.

Both do essentially the same thing: declare methods in another `.h` file. In either case, just include that `.h` file in the test class. This way the methods are only exposed to your tests.