# How to turn all public methods to internal methods?

Tags: c#, internal

Before deploying my project, I would like to set all `public` methods to `internal` methods. Does someone know a built-in function in Visual Studio or an external tool to do such tasks?

Comment: Search&Replace?

Comment: Search&Replace might still involve a lot of manual work, depending on whether OP wants only methods (properties, classes, interfaces, enums...) to become internal, or all public stuff...

Comment: @Chips_100 Exactly this is the problem. Some few methods should be excluded. So I thought there may be a tool, which once configured, does all the task for me automatically over and over again.

Comment: You could use Roslyn.

Comment: Perhaps you're approaching this from the wrong direction. Why do you need the methods to be public during development, if they don't need to be public during deployment?

Comment: This seems like a somewhat silly waste of time.  Changing to accessibility to *internal* doesn't stop other code that uses Reflection to get to your methods anyway.  It is *very* unclear why you made them public in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With some trivial refactoring, [ILMerge](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/people/mbarnett/ilmerge.aspx) can work here. ILMerge can merge multiple assemblies into one, and change the accessibility of everything that is not part of the primary assembly to `internal`. By separating your current project into two projects (a library containing all the code, and a helper executable that does nothing but forward to the real code in the library), you can, after a build, merge them back into a single file, in which all the library bits are no longer public.

Answer (score 1):

If you have properties/methods public for test reasons you should have a look at Brad Wilsons blog: [Testable Object Pattern](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2011/06/the-testable-object-pattern.html)

This way you don't have to switch, everything stays internal in development.

Or have a look at Jon Skeets suggestion on [InternalsVisibleTo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/204744/1045728)

Answer (score 0):

I can only think of two reasons you would want to do this:

- Security. In this case you have the wrong idea: access modifiers are **not** a security mechanism. They are a *design* concern, describing how an API presents itself. Any debugger will still give access to all your methods, regardless of their access modifiers.
- You have another assembly that you use during development that should have full access. In this case you can leave everything `internal` and make it a [friend assembly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0tke9fxk.aspx).

Comment: You are right, security reasons are the motivation behind my question. I see your point that accessors are the wrong approach. What kind of security techniques would you suggest instead?