# How to restrict class members to only one other class

Tags: c#, class

I want to access class members that are in `Class1` from another class (`Class2`) but I want to access it just from that class and to forbid access form any other class, form, etc. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: I changed the title of your question slightly, since you seemed to indicate you were having trouble with it.  If I got it wrong feel free to change it again, or change it back.

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Answer (score 4):

The only way to do this is to nest the classes, and then make the data private:

```
public class Class1
{
    private object data;
    public class Class2
    {
        public void Foo(Class1 parent)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(parent.data);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use nested class with `private` scope:

```
public class Class2
{
    public Class2()
    {
        Class1 c1 = new Class1();
        Console.WriteLine(c1.Id);
    }                

    private class Class1
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: The question seems to indicate that both classes should be public but that any other classes can't access the instance data of either.  This doesn't accomplish that.  This prevents access to `Class1` entirely from any other type.

Comment: I think that he/she want to prevent access to class (`Class1`) members at all. This question doesn't specify, if `Class1` can be used by other classes than `Class2`.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you can do this with a bit of lateral thinking. One way is to create a method on Class1 that accepts an instance of Class2 and returns delegates to access the members which are marked private. Then declare Class2  as sealed to prevent someone sneaking in with inheritance.

Another way would be to inspect the call stack with a StackFrame in each member (fields are out for this) and throw an Exception if the caller isn't the desired type.

Lord knows.why you'd do this though! :)

Comment: Obviously I'm assuming the nested class option is not available. :)

Comment: I came here because I was using the state pattern to model a state machine and I was concerned that the method `setState` in the context class is public, which allows the user of the context to transition between each pair of states, and I don't want that to be possible. Limiting access to `setState` only to the classes implemeting the `State` interface, if possible, seems like a way to circumvent this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can make an interface, that expose properties for access to your private members. And implement it explicitly. Than use that interface in other class. 
2-nd way is to use reflection.
3-rd is nested classes.

Answer (score -1):

You want a c# equivalent of "friend", but there isn't really one. This [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/204739/what-is-the-c-sharp-equivalent-of-friend)  gives possible solutions.

Comment: the equivalent of `friend` in c# is `internal` if you consider that an assembly is the equivalent of a package.

Comment: friend typically operates on classes, not packages (e.g. c++). It's not the same as internal as you suggest.

Comment: I thought you were talking about Java. I don't know about C++

Answer (score -1):

you may implement a property

```
[IsAllowed(true)]
public class a
{

}
```

then at your,method you may change the sign of each method requiring the instance.

```
public class b {
   public void method ( object aClassInstace){
     .... Here check the property
   }
}
```