# How to share property/method with parent class but not public?

Tags: c#

I'm not sure if my question is worded right, but I have a class that needs to make a property available to any class that instantiates it, but not make that property public. As an example:

```
public class MyClass1
{
    private double _PrivateNum = 9499488.07;
    private double PrivateNum
    {
        get
        {
            return _PrivateNum;
        }
    }
}
```

I want to create an instance of MyClass1 inside of MyClass2 and be able to access `PrivateNum` from MyClass2, but I don't want `PrivateNum` to be available outside of MyClass2. I know `private double PrivateNum` is not the correct, of course.

```
public class MyClass2
{ 
    public MyClass1 myclass1 = new MyClass1();

    public double GetSomeData
    {
        double PrivateNum = myclass1.PrivateNum;  <<== How do I set this in MyClass1
    }                                                  so I can access it in MyClass2,  
}                                                      but be unavailable outside
                                                       of MyClass2?
```

I just whipped up this example to illustrate what I'm wanting to accomplish. As I recall, VB uses `shared` to accomplish this. How is it done in C#?

Comment: Perhaps you want something like a [friend class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/204739/what-is-the-c-sharp-equivalent-of-friend).

Comment: What are you really trying to accomplish? Seems like a lot of hoops to jump through when any consuming class could easily make the value available to any other class.

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense to me, because If you want to make the property available to _any_ class that instantiates it, it has to be public. Even if it's public it won't be available to other classes that don't instantiate it. What's the actual problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: MyClass2 is a base product with a price (and lots of other product info). `<List>MyClass1` contains information about options/accessories a user has chosen for the base product. Most times, the options/accessories price is intended to be displayed to the user for choices they have made for the product, but sometimes the option/accessory acts as a base price modifier. The requirement in these isolated cases is to deduct the option price from the base price, but the option price should not be seen or transmitted to the client. This class gets sent as Json so I don't want it publicly accessible.

Comment: @rwkiii I would suggest that a better way to handle it would be to expose a view (api) model that gets populated rather than your domain models. That way you can use the domain->api model mapping along with, perhaps separate, business logic calculators to populate the view model with exactly that data that should be exposed.

Answer (score 1):

C# does not have the concept of `friend`s as C++ does. A similar idea is `internal` though. If you mark the property as `internal`, only classes in the package can use it. Of course this requires your design allows putting `MyClass1` and `MyClass2` in the same package.

Answer (score 0):

There is no `friend` classes in C#. But if you want to expose data only to class which creates instance of `MyClass1`, then you can use ugly code with callback returned from `MyClass1` constructor:

```
public class MyClass1
{
    private double _privateNum = 9499488.07;

    public MyClass1(out Func<double> callback)
    {
        callback = () => _privateNum;
    }

    // ...        
}
```

Now only class which instantiates `MyClass1` instance will have access to this callback:

```
public class MyClass2
{
    private Func<double> callback;
    public MyClass1 myclass1;

    public MyClass2()
    {
        myclass1 =  new MyClass1(out callback);
    }

    public double GetSomeData()
    {
        double privateNum = callback();
        // ...
    }
}
```

And, of course, you always can use reflection and keep data private to all classes:

```
Type type = myclass1.GetType();
var flags = BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic;
var field = type.GetField("_privateNum", flags);
double privateNum = (double)field.GetValue(myclass1);
```

Comment: I understand your first example better and yes, it is ugly. The second example looks ugly to me too but probably because I don't comprehend reflection yet. Thank you, your first answer is an idea even though it's not the prettiest.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you just make the variable `protected` in your `MyClass1` and then just subclass `MyClass1` with `MyClass2`?

Comment: MyClass1 is actually a `<List>` instantiated in MyClass2. I provided a better explanation in a comment to Bryan.

Answer (score 0):

As I see from your comment, you don't want some data to be transferred to client. Its very easy to do - just map your `MyClass2` objects to other class `MyClass3` which do not have data you want to hide. You can use AutoMapper for that.