# How can I share variables or properties between classes?

Tags: c#, blazor

Is there a way to share variables or properties between two classes?

For example, I have a Blazor web app with 2 pages and 2 partial classes. How can I share the variable A from class 1 with class 2?

Is there a way to do this?

I would be very grateful for an answer.

Comment: Members of every class are stored in memory. When you access member of Class1, this is different location from any member in Class2. Do you want something like *friend function* in C++? There is already question about this: [equivalent of friend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/204739/what-is-the-c-sharp-equivalent-of-friend)

Answer (score 3):

You could transfer the property through the parameter of the constructor.
So for instance you are in Form1 and want to transfer `variable_A` to `Form2` then you simply put `variable_A` in the constructor of `Form2`.

The code in `Form1`:

```
 private void GoToSecondForm_Click(object sender,eventarg e)
 {
   Form2 f = new Form2(variable_A);
   this.Hide();
   f.ShowDialog();
 }
```

Code in the constructor of `Form2`:

```
 {dataType} variable_A;
 public Form2({dataType} variable_A)
 {
   InitailizedComponent();
   this.variable_A = variable_A;
 }
```

If you do this then you will be able to use a variable in another form.

Comment: Mmm, giving a "how we might do it in winforms" answer to a Blazor question might not be too helpful..

Answer (score 1):

If you have a class with a member variable that you want to be accessed in another class, you will want to include accessor/mutator (getter/setter) methods in the first class. For example, if you had two classes A and B, and A had a variable `x` that you wanted to access, you would do something like this:

```
public class A {
  private int _x = 0;

  public int getX() {
    return this._x;
  }
  public void setX(int x) {
    this._x = x;
  }
}


public class B {
  A a = new A();

  public int returnX() {
    a.setX(8);
    return a.getX();
  }
}
```

The `returnX` function would return 8 in this case. If we didn't set `_x` to 8, it would return 0, as that is what `_x` is initialized to when new `A()` is called. You can make `_x` a public variable and access it by writing something like `a._x` in B, but this is generally considered bad practice.

Answer (score 1):

I'm making an assumption that by "Classes" you mean "Blazor Components".

If so, a simple way is via a Scoped Data Service through Dependency Injection.

Your Service:

```
    public class MyDataService
    {
        public int MyInt { get; set; }
    }
```

Add to the Services container in Program:

```
builder.Services.AddSingleton<WeatherForecastService>();
// The service
builder.Services.AddScoped<MyDataService>();
```

Any Component/Page can set or consume it.

```
@page "/"
@inject MyDataService DataService
<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

Welcome to your new app.

<SurveyPrompt Title="How is Blazor working for you?" />

@code {
    private int myInt = 0;
    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        this.DataService.MyInt = 2;
        //...
        myInt = this.DataService.MyInt;
    }
}
```