# Generic Repository Inconsistent accessibility

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, generics, repository-pattern

Using code below:

```
public IGenericRepository<TEntity> Repository<TEntity>() where TEntity : class
    {
        if (repositories.Keys.Contains(typeof(TEntity)) == true)
        {
            return repositories[typeof(TEntity)] as IGenericRepository<TEntity>;
        }
        IGenericRepository<TEntity> repo = new GenericRepository<TEntity>(_context);
        repositories.Add(typeof(TEntity), repo);
        return repo;
    }
```

The Error I got,

> Error 1   Inconsistent accessibility: return type
>   'DataModel.GenericRepository.IGenericRepository' is less
>   accessible than method
>   'DataModel.UnitOfWork.UnitOfWork.Repository()'    C:\Users\Anoop.k\documents\visual
>   studio
>   2013\Projects\WebAPI\DataModel\UnitOfWork\UnitOfWork.cs   30  44  DataModel

I know that IGenericRepository repo is private by default. But in this sort of situation what to do? 
Please help me.

Comment: is IGenericRepository your interface? Why would interface be set as private?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should define your Interface as public.

Or try this:

```
public IGenericRepository<TEntity> Repository<TEntity>() where TEntity : class
{
        if (repositories.Keys.Contains(typeof(TEntity)) == true)
        {
            return repositories[typeof(TEntity)] as IGenericRepository<TEntity>;
        }
        GenericRepository<TEntity> repo = new GenericRepository<TEntity>(_context);
        repositories.Add(typeof(TEntity), repo);
        return repo;
}
```

Comment: Ah, now I see it. It might be a good idea, then, to point out where it's different.

Answer (score 1):

You can't return a private type from a public method.

Change the accessibility of the `IGenericRepository` to public if you want other classes to be able to use it.

See also [What is a private interface?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/792908/what-is-a-private-interface)