# Why can a class implement its own private nested interface in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, oop, inheritance, interface

The following code is a valid C# construct that compile juste fine.

```
public class Weird : Weird.IWeird
{
    private interface IWeird
    {
    }
}
```

What would be the possible uses of this?

Edit: This question is more specific that this one: "[What is a private interface?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/792908/what-is-a-private-interface)". It shows that it's possible to implement a private interface from the parent type itself, which seems to be rather pointless. The only use I can think of would be a weird case of interface segregation where you would want to pass an instance of the parent class to a nested class instance as `IWeird`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a private interface?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/792908/what-is-a-private-interface)

Comment: If you have a nested private class that implements the interface, too, you might want to pass around `this` or an instance of that class by the private interface? Rather esoteric stuff, though :-)

Comment: What's the issue? That a public class can implement a private interface? That a class can implement a nested interface? Just the conjunction of those two?

Comment: You are using a [Marker Interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marker_interface_pattern) using an inner interface. Although its valid and it has no purpose outside. Short answer - There are no Uses

Comment: Does it compile? [Mono's C# reports an error](http://ideone.com/o1VUEt).

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever The conjunction of the two. There is no issue though, its just surprising.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Interesting. Yes, it compiles.

Comment: This should not compile giving circular reference error.

Comment: Gives an error when compiled: Circular base class dependency

Comment: I can confirm it *does* compile under Roslyn. It's *almost* circular but I don't think it is. The interface definition doesn't seem to have any dependencies.

Comment: @shanky - Why do you think that?

Answer (score 3):

This is probably one of these situations in compiler development when prohibiting something has a higher cost than allowing it. Prohibiting this use would require writing and maintaining code to detect this situation, and report an error; if the feature works as-is, this is an additional work for the team, and it could be avoided. After all, perhaps someone with good imagination could figure out a way to use the feature.

As far as a useful example goes, one potential use is to make another implementation in the class, and use it as an alternative without exposing it to the users of the API:

```
public class Demo : Demo.Impl {
    // Private interface
    private interface Impl {
        public bool IsValidState {get;}
        void DoIt();
    }
    // Implementation for the error state
    private class Error : Impl {
        public bool IsValidState { get { return false; } }
        public void DoIt() {
            Console.WriteLine("Invalid state.");
        }
    }
    private readonly string name;
    // Implementation for the non-error state
    public bool IsValidState { get { return true; } }
    public void DoIt() {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello, {0}", name);
    }
    // Constructor assigns impl depending on the parameter passed to it
    private readonly Impl impl;
    // Users are expected to use this method and property:
    public bool IsValid {
        get {
            return impl.IsValidState;
        }
    }
    public void SayHello() {
        impl.DoIt();
    }
    // Constructor decides which impl to use
    public Demo(string s) {
        if (s == null) {
            impl = new Error();
        } else {
            impl = this;
            name = s;
        }
    }
}
```

As far as best practices go, this design is questionable at best. In particular, I would create a second nested class for the non-error implementation, rather than reusing the main class for that purpose. However, there is nothing terribly wrong with this design (apart from the fact that both `IsValidState` and `DoIt` are visible) so it was OK of the C# team to allow this use.