# Why there are no friend classes in C#?

Tags: c#, inheritance, oop

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does C# not provide the C++ style ‘friend’ keyword?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203616/why-does-c-not-provide-the-c-style-friend-keyword)

A typical example where it might be needed

I have a class with private `Init()` function and class factory
which I would like to grant access to `Init()`;

Comment: This is a duplicate question: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203616/why-does-c-not-provide-the-c-style-friend-keyword](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203616/why-does-c-not-provide-the-c-style-friend-keyword)

Answer (score -1):

There are no friends in C#, it's true, but you can put these classes into same file, so they both will be able to access each other's functions. Or use "partial" classes, putting only init() function of each class into the same file where your factory resides

Comment: 'but you can put these classes into same file' - that certainly doesn't grant access to private members.