# How is the interaction between LinkedList<T> and LinkedListNode<T> implemented in C#?

Tags: c#, .net

First, let's define a node:

```
LinkedListNode<int> node = new LinkedListNode<int>(43);
```

You'll notice that the properties `node.List`, `node.Next` and `node.Previous` are all `get` only. Now let's add the node to a `LinkedList`:

```
LinkedList<int> linkedlist = new LinkedList<int>();
linkedlist.AddFirst(node);
```

At this point, the property `node.List` will have change to contain a reference to `linkedlist`. Similarly, if other nodes are added to the `LinkedList`, the `Next` and `Previous` properties will be updated to reflect the structure of the linked list, even though these properties do not expose a public `set` accessor.

How is this behavior implemented?

I know how to do it using `internal`, but is there a better way? For example, suppose I have a single assembly that contains many types, not just `LinkedList` and `LinkedListNode`. By making the setters for the node properties `List`, `Previous` and `Next`, I am exposing these setters to the whole assembly, which is undesired.

Answer (score 3):

> How is this behavior implemented?

Without looking at the source, I would guess the setters or backing fields for those properties are marked `internal` and therefore accessible from `LinkedList<T>` since they both sit in the same assembly.

> but is there a better way?

Not really. Let me elaborate. There are other options.

1. You could make `LinkedListNode<T>` an inner class defined in `LinkedList<T>`. That's an option, but it's burdensome on callers.
2. You could carve `LinkedList<T>` and `LinkedListNode<T>` into their own assembly. That's obviously a burden on users and could quickly degrade into a maintenance debacle.

I characterize both of these as not being *better* solutions.

Comment: Some implementations make the node class an inner class of the linked list; that's the other way of solving the problem.

Comment: Well, that adds other problems. I wouldn't characterize that as a *better* way.

Comment: Well, generally the nodes in a linked list are an implementation detail that the user doesn't need to know about at all, which is usually how such implementations are designed.  Personally I do think that's better.  There isn't any reason for the node to be public.

Comment: @Servy: Oh, you mean as a *`private`* inner class. Yes, that I would completely agree with, it's always puzzled me that `LinkedListNote<T>` is `public`. My answer is in the context of `LinkedListNode<T>` being public given the question was about the mechanism for how `LinkedListNode<T>`'s properties are modified given they aren't `public`.

Comment: @Servy If `LinkedListNode<T>` is private, how do you expose `Next` and `Previous`?

Comment: @becko You do so through an iterator.  If it was a forward only linked list the `IEnumerable` would be fine.  If your iterator needs additional functionality then you'd create the appropriate interface with the appropriate functionality and have the list itself have a method/property that creates an iterator.

Answer (score 1):

I checked with ILSpy, the read-only properties are backed by `internal` fields.

```
internal LinkedListNode<T> next;

public LinkedListNode<T> Next {
    get {
        if (this.next != null && this.next != this.list.head) {
            return this.next;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

As for how to do it differently, and a discussion of whether you'd want to, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6613613/in-c-sharp-4-0-is-there-any-way-to-make-an-otherwise-private-member-of-one-clas) and its answers.

Answer (score 1):

Jason is correct. I had a look at the source and `LinkedListNode<T>` has internal backing fields.

One way to do this is with nested classes. I don't know if this qualifies as a "better" way, but it does avoid internal setters/fields. I've left out some of the implementation, so you can see an outline of the structure:

```
public class Node<T>
{
  private List list;
  private Node<T> prev, next;

  public List List { get { return list; } }
  // other accessors.

  public abstract class List
  {
    Node<T> head;

    internal List() { }

    public AddFirst(Node<T> node)
    {
        // node adding logic.
        node.list = this;       
    }

    // implementation elided for brevity
  }

}

public class MyLinkedList<T> : Node<T>.List { }
```

Now you can declare a `MyLinkedList` and add nodes to it, but there are no internal accessors on `Node<T>`.

Comment: So you put `LinkedList` inside of `Node`... I have to say that is weird.

Comment: @becko Yes I agree. Its more of a curiosity than something I would actually suggest you implement.