# C# Access a method from one class, and not another

Tags: c#, methods, private-members

and sorry in advance if this question has been solved previously.

I am creating a small library in C# and am hoping to have class A be able to modify the data members of class B, where class A and B exist in the same namespace, C.D. This is not a problem to accomplish though I would like class E, in namespace C, to not be able to access the data members of B.

```
namespace C.D
{
    class B
    {
        modifier int
            a,
            b;

        public B()
        {
        }
    }

    class A
    {
        public A() {}

        public B DoStuff()
        {
            B b = new B();
            b.a = 1; b.b = 2;
            return b;
        }
    }
}

namespace C
{
    class E
    {
        static void Main(String[] args)
        {
            A a = new A();
            B b = a.DoStuff();
        }
    }
}
```

In my main method above I would like every class in the namespace C.D to be able to alter the data members of a class B object though nothing outside of the C.D namespace to be able to modify class B object data members.

Is there any way to do this by changing the namespace structure, modifiers, or implementing specific design patterns?

Thank you all in advance. : )

Comment: [Might be worth reading](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203616/why-does-c-sharp-not-provide-the-c-style-friend-keyword)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the "internal" access modifier if you're willing to move the relevant classes in C.D to a separate assembly.

```
namespace C.D
{
    class B
    {
        internal int a;
        internal int b;

        public B()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I read over the internal modifier though was hoping there would be a different way to implement a solution to my problem. I guess I just have to not be lazy : )

Comment: You're welcome. There are other ways around this. For example, you could create an interface for class B that exposes the necessary properties/methods. The classes that need to fiddle with internal details would be provided with the concrete implementation (or another interface) somehow. But this sort of restructuring is obviously a _lot_ more work.

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve this is by:

1. Moving Class A's definition into Class B (nesting it within `class B { ... }`)
2. Making Class B's fields (`a` and `b`) `private`.

i.e.

```
namespace C.D
{
    class B
    {
        private int a, b;

        public B()
        {
        }

        class A
        {
            public A() { }

            public B DoStuff()
            {
                B b = new B();
                b.a = 1; b.b = 2;
                return b;
            }
        }
    }
}

namespace C
{
    class E
    {
        static void Main(String[] args)
        {
            A a = new A();
            B b = a.DoStuff();
        }
    }
}
```

Another way to achieve this is to make Class B's fields `protected`, then make all classes that should have access to Class B's fields derive from Class B. This way you won't need to nest Class A inside Class B. i.e.

```
namespace C.D
{
    class B
    {
        protected int a, b;

        public B()
        {
        }
    }

    class A : B
    {
        public A() {}

        public B DoStuff()
        {
            B b = new B();
            b.a = 1; b.b = 2;
            return b;
        }
    }
}

namespace C
{
    class E
    {
        static void Main(String[] args)
        {
            A a = new A();
            B b = a.DoStuff();
        }
    }
}
```