# Closely linked classes with behaviour similar to C++'s "friend"

Tags: c#

I'm developing a system in C# for communication with a server (custom protocol over Sockets).

Without going into much detail about the context, I have two classes - `ServerConnection` and `ServerMessage`. The `ServerConnection` objects are capable of creating `ServerMessage` objects, which encapsulate information about the status of a reply.

However, `ServerConnection` is the class that handles all the data sending/receiving, and then sets the the relevant `ServerMessage`'s properties asynchronously (all messages are held in an internal list until the relevant reply is received, whereupon it is edited and removed).

As `ServerConnection` needs to fiddle around with the internal workings of the `ServerMessage` (at the moment, I need it to be able to trigger a `ManualResetEvent`), it needs more access to that class than I want other classes to have.

I believe that Nested classes give access in a similar way, but I've so far failed to create the desired hierarchy.

*Clarification: I want `ServerConnection` to be the programmer's interface, and to provide information on operations through the use of `ServerMessage`s.

Any ideas?

Comment: C++ doesn't support the notion of modules at the language level so requires you to be explicit about whom can mess with your private parts.  No such problem in C#, simply declare them as *internal*.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does C# not provide the C++ style 'friend' keyword?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203616/why-does-c-sharp-not-provide-the-c-style-friend-keyword)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe what you are looking for is internal - accessible within the same assembly.

Comment: Sorry, my question is quite confusing - I need both `ServerConnection` and other classes to have access to `ServerMessage`, but for `ServerConnection` to have "deeper" access  - to be able to access functions etc. that other classes cannot.

Comment: There are no true friend classes in c#. With internal fields or methods you'll be able to access then with your code (in the same assembly) but other code (different assembly) will not be able to.

Comment: But that requires splitting these two classes into a different assembly :/

Comment: Realistically, I'm the only person who'll ever use these classes (personal project), but it doesn't feel right have publicly available methods that can break the object's functionality if called externally

Comment: No, you put ServerConnection ands ServerMessage in the same assembly and they'll be able to access each other's internal fields. Other code will not.

Comment: Sorry, I understood your answer, but given the choice between creating a library for only 2 classes and having objects expose code that can break the object, I'm not sure which to pick :(

Comment: I would expose public methods that do all the manipulations that keep the class consistent. Example if I always have to change two properties together, have a method with two params that sets those two properties.